# How do you explicitly compute the p-torsion points on a general elliptic curve in Weierstrass form?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Consider the Weierstrass cubic
$$y^2z = x^3 + A\, xz^2+B\,z^3.$$
This defines a curve $E$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, which if smooth is an elliptic curve with basepoint at $[0,1,0]$.

I'm interested in having an *explicit* description of the locus of $p$-torsion points of this curve, where $p$ is prime.

In fact, suppose $p\neq 3$.  Then ideally I'd like to be able to find a curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, given by an equation $f=0$ of degree $d=(p^2-1)/3$, so that the scheme $X=E\times_{\mathbb{P}^2} C$ is precisely the locus of points of *exact* order $p$.

*Example:* For $p=2$, it's well known that $f=y$ gives such a curve.

I'd like $f$ to be an *expression which depends on $A$ and $B$*; i.e., I want to do this over a generic part of the moduli stack.  I would also like this expression to work *in characteristic p*;  in this case, $X$ should turn out to be the "scheme representing Drinfeld level structures $\mathbb{Z}/p\to E$".  (**Edit:** I'm particularly interested in families of curves which include supersingular curves.)

(My example curve $E$ is never smooth in characteristic $2$, but if you consider a more general Weierstrass form which is smooth in char. $2$, then you can find a degree $1$ curve $C$ which does what I ask.  For instance, if $E: y^2z+A\,xyz+yz^2=x^3$, take $f=A\,x+2\,y+z$.)

So my questions are:

1. Is it usually possible to find an equation $f=0$ such that $E\cap C$ is *exactly* the $p$-torsion?  (Is this the same as asking that $X$ is a complete intersection?)  Can you ever show it's *not* possible?
2. Are there known methods for computing the locus of $p$-torsion points explicitly?  Are there software packages which do this?  (I'm aware there are ways to find explicit torsion points on elliptic curves defined over some field or number ring; I'm asking for something a little different, I think.)
3. Have people carried out these sorts of computations for various small values of $p$ (even $p=5$), and are these computations described in print?  (I'm probably most interested in this question.)

**Warning:** I am not an algebraic geometer or number theorist.

Answer (score 10):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials

That's not the best wikipedia page. "The division polynomials form an elliptic divisibility sequence." is mentioned well before the far more important "the roots of the n'th division polynomial tell you the n-torsion in the curve".

Comment: PS finite flat group schemes are always complete intersections ;-)

Comment: Okay, I will look into that!  I'm worried it's not what I want, though.  The roots of the division polynomial $\psi_p$ are the $x$-coordinates of the $p$-torsion points, which means it degenerates in characteristic $p$ to something of smaller degree; it will never give the thing I want if the curve is supersingular, for instance.  

But since the algorithm seems to give a formula for $[n]:E\to E$, maybe I can get what I want out of it ...

Comment: I'll tell you a formula for [n]:E-->E; it's [n-1]+[1]. This works even in characteristic $p$. I am wondering whether if you think hard enough about this trivial observation that it will solve your problems without actually having to do any computations...

Comment: To be honest, perhaps the main contribution of the answer is telling you what to google for, rather than anything else...

Comment: PS @Charles: I've just realised that I don't understand your comment earlier about degenerations. You absolutely want the p'th division polynomial to degenerate mod p, because in characteristic p the identity of the group (the point at infinity) is a root of the equation [p]P=0 with multiplicity at least p, and hence you want some of the roots of the polynomial to go off to infinity, which is exactly what is happening.

Comment: I understand how the group law on an elliptic curve works.  But all expressions for $[n]$ and the group law I'm aware of (apparently including these division polynomials) are in terms of rational functions on $P^2$ or $P^2\times P^2$, which tend to have poles at the identity element of $E$, or at $\{(P,-P)\}$.  I probably didn't phrase my question well: in characterstic $p$, I don't just want the set $p$-torsion points, I want the scheme of $\Gamma_1(p)$-level structures in the sense of Drinfeld.  These include points "infinitesimally close" to the identity.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I agree that the $p$'th division polynomial has to degenerate mod $p$, for reasons you say.  The polynomial $f$ I'm looking for should not degenerate, however.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why giving explicit equations is regarded as a good idea to understand the scheme of Gamma_1(p)-structures.  What do you expect to learn from such equations?  Usually for any question about torsion on elliptic curves there are better ways to approach things than via division polynomials (especially if one is interested in something as subtle as schemes of Drinfeld structures).  It depends on what purpose you have in mind.  

Comment: For what it's worth, wikipedia seems to suggest that $\psi_p$ modulo $p$ should have degree $(p-1)/2$, which may have added to my confusion, since it seems to be false.  It actually appears that $\psi_5$ will have degree $10$ over $F_5$, and there has the form $\psi_5(x)=g(x^5)$ where $g$ is quadratic.  So it's better than I thought ...

Comment: @Brian: It's a long story, coming from homotopy theory.  There is a generalized cohomology theory  associated to universal deformation of a $1$-dim height $n$-formal group.  These theories come with  unstable cohomology operations, associated to isogenies which are deformations of the Frobenius isogeny.  I'd like to calculate the structure of the power operations in the case of $n=2$.  I know how to proceed (in principle) if I can answer this question, and I've done this for $p=2$.  Having an answer won't change the world, but might help me get a sense of what this says about homotopy.

Comment: @Charles: you don't want division polynomials if you're actually going to do serious arithmetic geometry over rings where p isn't invertible. My suggestion to use division polynomials is much too naive. If you really want to understand Drinfeld level structures then the problem you face is that when p isn't invertible these are very subtle notions. Forget division polynomials. What you want to do is to read Katz-Mazur really. Probably not the answer you want. On the other hand if you just want to understand the structure of the moduli space _locally_ then actually this is...(continued)

Comment: ...this is just linear algebra. Local equations for for X_1(p) can be computed relatively painlessly using standard facts about deforming elliptic curves; these work for all p. Is this enough for you?  There is even a table in Katz-Mazur explaining what the space looks like locally.

Comment: @Kevin.  Ok.  That's probably the thing for me to look at, then.  No reason to continue this conversation here till I do.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Charles: you could always ask Neil Strickland. He knows all about the generalised cohomology theory side of the story but also has a firm grasp on "Katz-Mazur from a practical point of view". It's perhaps people like him that might be able to give you the kind of answer that would be more to your taste.

Comment: @Charles: also, you don't want to know about division polynomials, you want to know about explicit equations for modular curves. I think "modular polynomials" would be better googling bet than division polynomials. 

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, modular polynomials look like a better bet!  Though the references I've googled so far seem to think that these polynomials only have the modular interpretation I want (classying $\ell$-isogenies) when $p\neq \ell$.   

Re Neil: Yes, I should ask him.  Actually, I'm sure he's thought about this exact problem.

Answer (score 7):

Since you asked about software, I'd just like to point out (if you don't know already) that SAGE (available at sagemath.org) can compute division polynomials easily.  The commands

`R.<A,B> = PolynomialRing(GF(5))`

`E = EllipticCurve([A,B])`

`f = E.division_polynomial(5)`

`f`

return the result

`2*A*x^10 - A^2*B*x^5 + A^6 - 2*A^3*B^2 - B^4.`

The warnings of the commenters apply;  you must be cautious about interpreting the division polynomials.  It is true that the roots of this polynomial give you the "physical" 5-torsion points of the elliptic curve in characteristic 5, but that's about all it says.  The polynomial does not tell you, eg, the structure of the group scheme E[5] over the supersingular locus.

A little more helpful might be the formal group associated to this family:

`G = E.formal_group()`

`G.mult_by_n(5,30)`

which returns

`2*A*t^5 + (2*A^6 - A^3*B^2 - B^4)*t^25 + O(t^30)`

There's also a command `G.group_law()` whose output I'm not going to give here.  Together these data give you the structure of E[5] over an infinitesimal neighborhood of the zero section of your elliptic curve over $\text{Spec}\mathbf{F}_5[A,B,\Delta^{-1}]$.

I'm a firm believer in explicit calculations as a means of developing intuition about algebro-geometric concepts.  But by all means read Katz-Mazur :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to answer my own question, using the "division
polynomials" of Kevin's and Jared's answers.   It is probably the maximally naive idea, and I do not claim it
works, though it's not clear to me that it can't.
I've community wiki-ed this answer, as it's probably junk anyway ...

Fix $A,B\in \mathbb{Z}$, obtaining an elliptic curve $E$ over $S=Spec
\mathbb{Z}[\Delta^{-1}]$, and a prime $p\geq 5$ not dividing the
discriminant $\Delta=\Delta(A,B)$.  The
division polynomial $\psi_p(t)$ is supposed to be a polynomial of
degree $d=(p^2-1)/2$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, whose roots are the values 
$t(P)=x(P)/z(P)$ as $P$ ranges over the points of exact order $p$ in
$E$.

Turn $\psi_p$ into a homogeneous polynomial $g$ of degree $d$ in
$\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$, so that $g(x,y,1)=\psi_p(x)$.  The polynomial
deterimes a curve $C=(g)$ in $P^2/S$, and thus a closed subscheme
$D=E\cap C$ of $E$.  Over $\mathbb{Z}[\Delta^{-1},p^{-1}]$, $D$ should
consist of 
the points of exact order $p$ on $E$ (with multiplicity $1$), together
with the basepoint of $E$ with multiplicity $d$.

**Claim.** $D$ is an *effective Cartier
divisor* on $E/S$, of degree $3d$.

*Proof.*  I don't know.  I need to prove that $D\to
S$ is flat, the main concern being the behavior over
$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.  I don't even know if this is really plausible in general.

Let's pretend we somehow know $D$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $E$
relative to the base $S$.  There is another relative Cartier
divisor, namely
$$ D' = E[p] \quad + \quad (d-1)[0]$$
where $E[p]$ is the $p$-torsion subgroup scheme of $E$, and $[0]$ is the
degree one divisor of the basepoint of $E$.
It seems clear that *away from characteristic $p$*, the divisors $D$
and $D'$ are equal.  Equality of effective divisors on a smooth curve
is a closed condition, so they should be equal over all of
$S$.

The divisor I want is thus $D''=D-d[0]=D'-d[0]$ (which is still
effective).  Then it's *really* easy to find a homogeneous polynomial
$h$ of degree $2d/3$ which defines $D''$; because of the form of the
Weierstrass equation, you can produce it from $g$ by hand, and if my claim is true you can produce it globally, i.e., with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[A,B]$.

I've carried out this out in the case $p=5$, and it appears to "work".
That is, I get an answer which appears sane for general $A$ and $B$, and
which for some explicit cases I've tried of $A,B\in \mathbb{Z}$ appears to give me a flat $D\to S$.
For instance, if $E/\mathbb{Z}[6^{-1}]$ is the curve with  $(A,B)=(0,1)$ (which reduces to a supersingular curve at $p=5$), I find
$$h= 729z^{8}-1350x^4z^4+360x^6z^2+5x^8.$$

Comment: What you seem to be doing is writing down the divisor $E[p]$ minus the identity section. I thought you wanted the scheme parametrising points of order $p$ in the sense of Drinfeld. The problem is that in characteristic $p$ the relationship between these two things is delicate. For example $E[p]$ minus the identity, over an ordinary elliptic curve over an alg closed field of char $p$, will typically have all its components non-reduced. But the moduli space for the Drinfeld level structure will have reduced components IIRC. I am unclear about what you want though.

Comment: If you're happy with $E[p]$ minus the identity then great. That sort of notion was understood in the 1960s. Drinfeld level structures are more subtle and weren't around until the 1980s.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused, or am using incorrect terminology.  The gadget I want should not have reduced components in char p; I want a Gamma_1(p) structure in the sense of Katz-Mazur, 3.2.

Comment: Well perhaps I am confused as well; I'll try and remember to look at my copy of K-M on Monday (you seem to indicate that I've forgotten what the special fibre of X_1(p) looks like, which might be true; I had thought it had two components, one a (reduced) Igusa curve and one non-reduced). But my point is this. Why should E[p] minus the origin represent points of order p in the sense of Drinfeld? If that's true (which it might be) then it's news to me. I'll try to remember to get back to you. If this trick works then you're in business!

Comment: Well, K-M define a $\Gamma_1(m)$ structure as a group homomorphism $f:Z/m\to E$ (equivalently, a choice of $f(1)\in E[m]$) which satisfies a certain condition (an inequality $\sum [f(i)]\leq E[m]$ of effective divisors).  This is a closed condition, so $\Gamma_1(m)$ is a closed subscheme of $E[m]/S$; I believe they show it is flat and finite over the base $S$ (KM 5.1.1), of rank $\#\text{injections}(Z/m,Z/m^2)$.   For $m=p$, this should do it, no?

Comment: @Charles: I really think this is no good. You seem to be suggesting that $E[p]$ minus the zero section is representing Drinfeld $\Gamma_1(p)$ structures. But here's a proof that this can't be true: consider a "universal" connected family of ordinary elliptic curves in characteristic $p$ (e.g. the ord locus of $X_1(N)$ mod p for some auxiliary $N>4$ prime to $p$). The object you suggest is representing the functor has $p$ components and none of them are reduced. The object that does represent the functor, according to the table on p417 of Katz-Mazur, has two components, one of which is reduced.

Comment: As for your argument in the comments above, I don't know what you mean by "$\Gamma_1(m)$ is a closed subscheme of...". Are you confusing a $\Gamma_1(m)$ structure with the moduli space representing $\Gamma_1(m)$ structures?

Comment: Another remark: this question has drifted down the list of questions and hence I am unlikely to notice if you respond to my comments above---the question only gets bumped to the top if someone posts a new answer, not a new comment. Hence if you want to alert me to any comments you have, we could continue the discussion by email.

Comment: @Charles: actually I am too hasty suggesting you have $p$ components because over a big base they might link up. I should localise and complete at a point on the base first.

Comment: I think I'm being dense about what I mean about "reduced".  Let's continue this in email.

Comment: The upshot of our email conversation was that my gut instinct above is _wrong_. I claim above that above the ordinary locus of the mod p modular stack, E[p] (finite flat over the stack and hence an abstract algebraic curve) has no reduced components. The reason I thought this was because its identity component is non-reduced, and "hence all the other components must be too". I can't prove this, and I am convinced by Charles' arguments, so my slip must be here. It seems to me that one can form Drinfeld Gamma_1(p) by throwing out the identity section of E[p]. My apologies to Charles.

Comment: @Charles: I posted some of my thoughts at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17782/components-of-ep-e-universal-in-char-p