# When does a group action on $X$ preserve the reduction $X_\text{red}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the action of an affine group scheme preserve the nilradical of an algebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68366/does-the-action-of-an-affine-group-scheme-preserve-the-nilradical-of-an-algebra)

Let the group scheme $G$ act on the scheme $X$. I labored for a time under the misapprehension that the reduced subscheme $X_\text{red}$ would be automatically $G$-invariant -- it's such a canonical subscheme, how could it leave?
But if $X=G$ is a nonreduced group scheme (e.g. {$g \in {\mathbb G}_m : (g-1)^p = 0$}), 
over a field of characteristic $p$), then this obviously fails.

> What is a good condition to ensure that $G$ preserves $X_\text{red}$? Is it enough to assume $G$ is itself reduced?

EDIT: As Angelo points out in his comment, this is nearly an exact duplicate. And of a question I evidently read, since I commented on it. Sigh.

Comment: I believe that the question is answered in <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68366/does-the-action-of-an-affine-group-scheme-preserve-the-nilradical-of-an-algebra/68374#68374> (at least in the affine case, but I think that the proof can be adapted to the general case)

Comment: Yes, if $G$ is smooth, then $G\times X_{red}$ is reduced, so the morphism $G\times X\to X$ defining the action of $G$ on $X$ induces a morphism $G\times X_{red}\to X_{red}$.